# Creating a MongoDB schema with references to other schemas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am having some difficulties understanding how construct my schemas and am hoping to get some help.
In short I have three schemas Company, User and Verification. I start by creating some companies and then create and add users to the companies.

I then log in to a webpage and use a form to add rows to a table (konto, beskrivning, projekt...). Then I save the verification to a MongoDB.

First question is: Would the current schemas work for my scenario? or do I need to change something. Have I entered redundant information?

Second question: In the VerificationSchema I would like to have an incrementing value (verificationNumber) for each company that starts by 1 then increases for every added verification. The counter should be separate for each company but shared with all users in the same company.

Verification.js

```
const VerificationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
verificationNumber: Number,
user :{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
company: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company'}, 
rows: [{
    konto: Number,
    beskrivning: String,
    projekt: String,
    debet: Number,
    kredit: Number
  }]
});
```

Company.js

```
const CompanySchema = mongoose.Schema({
companyName: String,  
users: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
verifications: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Verification'}]
});
```

User.js

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userName: String,  
    company: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company'],
    verifications: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Verification'}]
    });
```